# Detect if function called from a return statement

Tags: python, reflection, return, code-inspection

I'm using `inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]` to get the caller's frame in Python 2.7.
I would like to check whether the call came from a return statement. This is because I'm interfacing with a system that uses python as a kind of toolkit language, with some conventions that would deem this useful.

Is there a structured way to check if the caller is 'executing the current frame' *from a return statement*?

I was trying to inspect the source code with `inspect.getsourcelines(frame)` but it doesn't particularly look a good idea if the caller code is messy:

```
if foo(3, 'ugly # evil\' :"string"', """hey"""): return called(1,  # arg1
        my_favorite_constant, 'very long stuff', 'bad conventions',3) # comment
called(*stuff) # hey, not return -ing anything here.
```

So it would be better to do a structural check than string parsing. I was skimming the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module docs but not sure how to do it.

Comment: *Why* do you need to know this? What would you do with that knowledge? There is almost certainly [a better solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), if you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve. Even if there isn't, this knowledge at least helps judging e.g. whether false positives are acceptable, narrowing down the solution space.

Comment: @delnan the code tries to assemble some extra logging exclusively before some returning conventions. However I would like to warn any code-user that it is unexpected to use this function while not returning. Maybe exceptions should be used instead, but they are not in the current code-base, also these returns are not unexpected, and the needed objects are more natural to pass to a function. Exceptions also propagate upwards which is a shared code-base and change would affect more code-users than it needs to.

Comment: do you know the `with`-statement?

Comment: Yes but it's unclear to me what do you mean by it. Suppose you mean the logging could be done when the code exits the context. But the outer code expects a return. Also, would the `__exit__` access the internal block's variables?